# View doesn't display correct model data from controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am testing AngularJS as follow.

Script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);


myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope){
    var employee = {
        firstName = "Test",
        lastName = "Name",
        gender = "Male"        
    };
    $scope.employee = employee;    
});
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <div>  
            {{ employee.firstName }} 
        </div>
        <div>  
            {{ employee.lastName }} 
        </div>
        <div>  
            {{ employee.gender }} 
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the program, I just see as

```
{{ employee.firstName }}
{{ employee.lastName }}
{{ employee.gender }}
```

I don't see in correct format.
What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: First thing you should have done is look for the errors in your browser's console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in the way you are assigning values to the employee object , it should be like this,

```
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope){
    var employee = {
        firstName : "Test",
        lastName : "Name",
        gender : "Male"        
    };
    $scope.employee = employee;    
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/sqZj1BjaZYG0UDtkHkj8?p=preview)

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Comment: Yes yours is working. Yours and mine not different. Why mine is not working?

Comment: @batuman chec   firstName : "Nyan", you are assigning with an =

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125552/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-batuman).